# Play video chunks continuously in MediaElement

Tags: video, video-streaming, mediaelement.js

I have a recorded video which is split to a set of files. Also, I have a video recording in progress and there will be more chunks. I need to play these chunks on a web page as a single continuous video. Here is the requirements:

1. User should be able to view live video.
2. User should be able to navigate to any time point within whole range of all video chunks.
3. Timeline should be updated continuously while video is being recorded.

Can I complete this task by only means of MediaElement? Or should I use another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **HLS Event** playlists. They work exactly as described by your requirements. And it's an already established standard which will work across different devices/players.

See: [Example Playlist Files for use with HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-EVENT_PLAYLIST)